# Ajax request causes the page to reload - on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

The ajax code when is runned through a mobile device causes the page to reload and doesn't execute the insert ( does not even prom a error message ), on the other hand everything runs normally on the computer, any ideas why?

```
 $('#pending_request_submit').on("click",function() {

    var url = "http://leagueofmusic.com/mobix-html/lib/pending_request.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#pending_request").serialize(),
           beforeSend: function(){
            $('#request_response').html('<center><img src="css/img/loader.gif"></center>');
           },
           success: function(data)
           {
              $('#request_response').html(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: It's more likely that the `return false` isn't happening due to a javascript error. or that the event isn't triggering at all. Seeing the error would likely be very difficult due to the page reloading.

Comment: Also possible that on mobile it's triggering the submit event directly and skipping the click event, thus bypassing your event handler.

Comment: Start by adding `action="javascript:alert('would have refreshed')"` to the form to stop it from refreshing if the default isn't properly prevented, this will allow you to see errors (if any).

Comment: actually he pops it up and does nothing more than that :p

Comment: Then it's likely my other case is correct: it simply isn't triggering the click event. Try using a submit event instead.

Comment: I tried submit too also a onclick function :/

Comment: submit was bound to the form, not the button, right?

Comment: All is fine:) so basically a submit not onclick works. Also used the usb debugging, thanks for hints post a answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that whatever the mobile device is using to submit the form is directly submitting the form rather than clicking the submit button. Using a submit event instead will fix it in this case:

```
$('#pending_request_form').on('submit',function() {
```